# How to display the elements of an array with character index in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working with an array like this one :

```
var table = [a: 'text_1', b: 'test_2'];
```

I need to display all the elements of this array with a single function or method but we must consider that 'a' and 'b' are characters or strings, not numbers.

That's why I can't use the array.forEach() method !

Any idea?

Comment: That's invalid, at least almost, you can do it, but arrays should have numbered indexes, and objects should have keys

Comment: Array is something like `['a','b']`, but in your case your variable is bad-written  object, you should use `var table = {a: 'text_1', b: 'test_2'}` instead.

Comment: And if it is an object, you simply do `for (var key in table) { ...`

Comment: Thank you guys, I will use an object!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array declaration looks a little off. The code you've posted gives a syntax error.

---

If you want this to be an array, it should look something like this:

```
var table = ['text_1', 'test_2'];
```

You should be able to iterate through that with `forEach`:

```
table.forEach(function (entry) {
  // 'text_1', then 'test_2', etc...
});
```

---

If you want this to be an object with a string key, it should look something like this:

```
var table = {a: 'text_1', b: 'test_2'};
```

You can iterate through that like this:

```
// For every key in `table`...
var value;
for (var key in table) {

  // If the table has the key (and it isn't somewhere higher
  // up in the prototype chain...
  if (table.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    value = table[key];

    // ...do something with `value`...
  }
}
```

You can also use the popular [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) or [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) libraries to accomplish this in a prettier way:

```
_.each(table, function (value, key) {
  // ...do something with `value` and `key`...
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Evan for this long answer , I learned lots of things.

Answer (score 0):

You want something more like this:

```
var table = {a: 'text_1', b: 'test_2'};
for(key in table){
    console.log(key); //logs a and b
    console.log(table[key]); //logs 'text_1' and 'test_2'
}
```

Your table is an object, not an array.

Comment: Thank you @JeremyJackson, I will use an object!

Answer (score 0):

The data structure you want is a plain object:

```
var table = {a: 'text_1', b: 'test_2'};
```

You can use a normal object iterator loop (`for...in`), or if you want to access all Array methods, you can iterate over the object keys (for example, if you want to filter):

```
Object.keys(table).filter(function(key) {
  console.log(table[key]);

  return table[key] !== 'text_1';
});
```

Comment: Thank you Josh for you answer, I will try this filter method you gave me!

Comment: @TimothePearce `filter` has nothing to do with it, I was just showing an example of a use of a native Array method on a structure that is a plain object

Comment: Yes I had understood, it works like a charm, thank you ;)